# Why is my lemon tree losing leaves after I gave it tomato feed?

Tags: trees, tree-care, fertilizer, citrus

There are pale blotches on the leaves of my lemon tree. There are no pests or mites, but all leaves have fallen from tree. I have tried a tomato feed with no results.

Comment: picture please of top and bottom of leave and plant in general.  Do not feed with fertilizer again until it's diagnosed

Comment: Hi Liz and welcome! When you post your pictures, would you please add some additional information, including where you live, the age of the tree and what kind of soil it's growing in? More details will help people give you better answers.

Comment: Liz, which tomato fertilizer did you use? What were the N-P-K values?